Missing the 'mysql' inside /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ - MAMP on MacOS Ventura
Using the free version on MAMP. Please no answers about the Pro.
It used to work a month ago. Now it doesn't work anymore, and now everytime I run mysql -u root, Terminal throws ERROR zsh: command not found: myql.
My paths are set correctly
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/

However, when I view this in Finder Applications Directory, I don't see the "/mysql" part inside /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
as you can see in the photo.Screenshot of directory where MAMP is located in Finder. Why is the /mysql part not in my directory of /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/...
What else could be causing this problem? I have uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled it twice from the official mamp website. Why do I still get permission denied or command not found?
MAMP 7.0, MacOS 13.6.9

I tried adding the paths to .zshrc, /etc/paths and googled that up and down. So the paths are added.
Unlocked the file in Finder, get info area, also made sure that under Sharing & Permissions that it says Read & Write.
Tried sudo mysql -u root --> error sudo: mysql: command not foundor zsh: command not found: mysql
Uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP twice through download from mamp.info
Then tried with homebrew, however it kept telling me to delete a certain file, which I deleted, and ran brew install --cask mamp again, same file re-appears that, I per instructions delete. MAMP didn't install via homebrew.
So I installed it again vie mamp.info download


After spending 48 hours on this, searching the internet trying every single fix...
I thought back when the problem started happening, and realized it was since the update to MAMP 7.0.
SOLVED: Reverted back to MAMP 6.9 and it mysql -u root works again perfectly! The missing item in my directory is back again so that the path actually works. See updated Directory screenshot
